# How to add views from other model in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I'm creating a component in Joomla! 3.1.4 which contains multiple models. What I would like to accomplish is to add multiple models B that associate with model A in A's edit view.

To be specific, I want to keep adding unlimited number of model B to connect to model A when I am editing model A. And provide a simple list of B's in A's edit view.

This can of course be done in B's edit views, or fully hard coded within A's edit view. I believe Joomla! should have some methods to accomplish that to avoid code duplications.

Can anyone please shed a light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) website covers this subject in the article "[Using multiple models in an MVC component](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_multiple_models_in_an_MVC_component)"

Answer (score 1):

To call another model from the view, in the view display() method

```
$modelA = $this->getModel('ModelA');
$modelB = $this->getModel('ModelB');
```